# Need individual entry with Redux and Router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-redux

I'm using ReactJS, Redux (with server-side rendering) and react-router-redux [as set up here](https://github.com/choonkending/react-webpack-node) and am getting a little thrown by how routes work with the rest of the redux state and actions.

For example, I have a members component with the route `/members`:

```
class Members extends Component {

  static need = [
    fetchMembers
  ]

  render() {
    ...
```

the static `need` array specifies an action that populates an array on the state that is then mapped to the component props. That much works.

But then I have an individual member component with the route `members/:memberId`. How do I load that individual member in a way that works both client- and server-side.

What I'm doing now is the same:

```
class Member extends Component {

  static need = [
    fetchMembers
  ]

  render() {
    ...
```

but then map just the single member

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    member: state.member.members.find(member => member.id == ownProps.params.memberId),
  };
}
```

This works but is obviously wrong. So the question is two-fold:

1. When the user clicks the router `Link` that has a query param (:memberId), how do I use that router param to query a specific document (assume a mongo database). Do I somehow trigger a separate action that populates an `active` member field on the redux state? Where does this happen, in the route component's `componentDidMount`?
2. How does this work with server-side rendering?

Answer (score 1):

I’ve had the same question and seemed to find a way that works pretty well with my setup. I use Node, Express, React, React Router, Redux and [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk).

**1)** It really depends on where your data is. If the data needed for `/member/:memberId` is already in state (e.g. from an earlier call) you could theoretically filter through what you already have when `componentDidMount` is fired.

However, I'd prefer to keep things separate simply to avoid headaches. Starting to use one data source for multiple destinations/purposes throughout your app might give you long days down the road (e.g. when *Component A* needs more/less properties about the member than *Component B* or when *Component A* needs properties in a different format than *Component B* etc.).

This decision should of course be based on your use-case but due to the cost of API calls nowadays I wouldn't be afraid (at all) to make one when someone navigates to `/member/:memberId`.

**2)** I’ll answer with a simplified version of my typical setup:

Whenever a request comes through, I have this fella handle it.

```
// Imports and other jazz up here

app.use((req, res) => {

  const store = configureStore({});
  const routes = createRoutes(store);

  match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {

    if (error) {

      res.status(500).send(error.message);

    } else if (redirectLocation) {

      res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);

    } else if (renderProps) {

      const fetchedData = renderProps.components
        .filter(component => component.fetchData)
        .map(component => component.fetchData(store, renderProps.params));

      Promise.all(fetchedData).then(() => {

        const body = renderToString(
          <Provider store={store}>
            <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
          </Provider>
        );

        res.status(200).send(`<!doctype html>${renderToStaticMarkup(
          <Html
            body={body}
            state={store.getState()}
          />)
        }`);

      });

    } else {

      res.status(404).send('Not found');

    }

  });

});
```

It’ll look for `fetchData` on the components that are about to be rendered, and make sure we have the data before we send anything to the client.

On each and every route, I have a `Container`. The `Container`’s sole purpose is to gather the data needed for that route. As you’ve touched upon this can happen server-side (`fetchData` in my case) or client-side (`componentDidMount` in my case). A typical `Container` of mine looks like this:

```
// Imports up here

class Container extends Component {

  static fetchData(store, params) {
    const categories = store.dispatch(getCategories());
    return Promise.all([categories]);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(getCategoriesIfNeeded());
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.categories.length ? (
      // Render categories
    ) : null;
  }

}

Container.propTypes = {
  categories: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  params: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    categories: state.categories,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Container);
```

In the `Container` above I’m using `getCategories` and `getCategoriesIfNeeded` to make sure that I have the data needed for the route. `getCategories` is only called server-side, and `getCategoriesIfNeeded` is only called client-side.

Note that I have `params` available for both `fetchData` and `componentDidMount` (passed from `connect()`), which I could potentially use to extract something like `:memberId`.

The two functions used to fetch data above are listed below:

```
// Using this for structure of reducers etc.:
// https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux
//
// actionTypes object and reducer up here

export function getCategories() {

  return (dispatch, getState) => {

    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.GET_REQUEST,
    });

    return fetch('/api/categories').then(res => {

      return !res.error ? dispatch({
        error: null,
        payload: res.body,
        type: actionTypes.GET_COMPLETE,
      }) : dispatch({
        error: res.error,
        payload: null,
        type: actionTypes.GET_ERROR,
      });

    });

  };

}

export function getCategoriesIfNeeded() {

  return (dispatch, getState) => {

    return getState().categories.length ? dispatch(getCategories()) : Promise.resolve();

  };

}
```

As displayed above I have both `dispatch` and `getState` available thanks to [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) - that handles my promises too - which gives me freedom use the data I already have, request new data and do multiple updates of my reducer.

I hope this was enough to get you moving. If not don't hesitate to ask for further explanation :)

Comment: Great answer. It looks like the implementation I'm using comes out of this project: https://github.com/caljrimmer/isomorphic-redux-app. They use a similar approach to yours, but instead of using a static function on the component, call action creators. What I was missing was that it's tied to the router, so that action creator is passed the query params, which it can use to query the record being asked for.

Comment: Sweet, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer, it turns out, was pretty simple. The implementation taken from [Isomorphic Redux App](https://github.com/caljrimmer/isomorphic-redux-app) ties the `need` static property on a component back to the router by passing the routes query params into the action creator.

So for the route:

```
items/:id
```

you'd use a component like

```
class Item extends Component {

  static need = [
    fetchItem
  ]

  render() {
```

specifying that it needs the `fetchItem` action. That action is passed the route's query params, which you can use like

```
export function fetchItem({id}) {
  let req = ... 
  return {
    type: types.GET_ITEM,
    promise: req
  };
}
```

For a more detailed explanation about why this work, read marcfalk's answers, which describes a very similar approach.